# How do you determine purchase date when there are multiple stock buys?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, irs, capital-gain

1. I buy 5000 shares of ABC on `Jan/01/22` for $100,000 ($20.00/share)
2. I buy 2500 shares of ABC on `Feb/01/22` for $100,000 ($40.00/share)
3. I now have 7500 shares with a cost basis of $200,000 ($26.66/share)
4. I sell 2500 shares of ABC almost 1 year later on `Jan/15/23` for $125,000 ($50.00/share)

My capital gain is approximately ($50.00 - $26.66) * 2500 = $58,350

But what day of purchase should I use? `Jan/01/22` or `Feb/01/22`? Would it be considered short-term or long-term?

Comment: The keyword to use here is 'tax lot'. Your broker should have an option to see the tax lots somewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Brokers default to FIFO (first in, first out), so unless you instructed your broker to sell the shares purchased on 2/1/22 they will have sold the ones you acquired on 1/1/22. Since the holding period on those is longer than 1 year it is long-term.

Your capital gain is not calculated using average cost, but actual for the shares sold, so in your example 30*2500 (assuming FIFO).

Comment: Since the shares are fungible and interchangeable with each other. Can I retroactively go back and elect for a different interpretation on which shares were sold? Or is this some setting that I should've known about at the start of the tax year and there is no going back now?

Comment: @AlanSTACK My understanding is that you generally have until the trade has settled to correct a FIFO/LIFO/specific lot selection. Otherwise, which shares are sold is determined at the time the order is executed and is irrevocable. This previous answer seems to support that: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/145639/121074

Comment: @AlanSTACK Stan H is correct, has to happen before settlement. You'll have to check your broker's documentation, for mine it requires an email after the trade goes through that includes all relevant info.

Comment: In my case, my broker follows the policy I have set (FIFO, LIFO, etc.) when determining which shares were sold, and I get a tax summary at the end of the year which lists the shares sold, their purchase price, their sale price, and whether the sale should be counted as wash sale, short term, or long term. I make absolutely no effort to track that myself, since before the end of the year (and taxes) it has essentially no effect on me.

Comment: @keshlam Do you know if FIFO and LIFO are the only policies available? Or are there more?

Comment: @AlanSTACK It would depend on the broker, but the ones I'm familiar with are happy for you to specify specific numbers of shares from each lot, so essentially "all the policies" are available.

Comment: Unless you're loss harvesting, though, it rarely makes sense to choose anything other than FIFO.

Comment: @Sneftel:  In this case, if the sale were Feb 18 it would incur less capital gains tax to sell the newer shares.

Comment: You'll just have the same gains later.Unless cg pushes you over the tax bracket line, I consider this a difference that makes no difference.

Comment: @keshlam But by postponing your capital gains taxes, you can keep the money that will eventually be payed in tax invested and get returns on them, so selling the shares with least gains on them seems best to me. I struggle to see why FIFO would generally be considered best.

Comment: FIFO generally avoids short-term gains, which many of us consider a larger immediate nuisance.

Comment: @keshlam Okay, I just googled short-term gains tax so now I understand. I'm not from the US and we don't have anything like that.